# Number of vectors whose sum of components multiplied by position is a constant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I am interested in the vectors $(v_1, \dots, v_m)$  with $v_i \in \mathbb{N}$ for $1\leq i \leq  m$,  such as the linear diophantine equation:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m} iv_i = n
$$
holds.

For instance there are 7 vectors such that for n=5, and avoiding zeros at the right:

(5)
(3,$\,$1)
(1,2)
(2,0,1)
(0,1,1)
(1,0,0,1)
(0,0,0,0,1)

Is there a explicit formula for determining the number of vectors with this property for a given n? I have found a recursive formula but it would be great is the explicit versions exists.

The recursive definition says that the number of vectors that represent n is s(n,n), where
$$
 s(n,m) =
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $n=0$} \\
    1 & \text{if $n>0, m=1$} \\
    1+ \sum_{i=0}^{i\leq \frac{n}{m}} s(n-i\cdot m, m-1) & \text{if $n>0, m>1, n \mod m=0$} \\
    \sum_{i=0}^{i\leq \frac{n}{m}} s(n-i\cdot m, m-1)  & \text{if $n>0, m>1, n \mod m \neq 0$}
  \end{cases}
$$
For instance $s(5,5)=7$ because $$s(5,5) = 1 + \underbrace{s(5,4)}_{6} + \underbrace{s(0,4)}_{0}$$
I would also like to know if the vectors with this property are well-known in the sense that they have been studied before. Thanks!

Comment: What is the recursive formula? Someone may be able to solve it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion. I have added the recursive formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$, and specifically the number of partitions of $n$ into parts not greater than $m$. These numbers are well studied; you'll find lots of material in the Wikipedia article, and by searching for "partition" on this site, and under the [partitions](/questions/tagged/partitions) tag.